# Multiple seasonality with ARIMA?

Tags: time-series, arima

I know that ARIMA can't detect multiple seasonality, but it is possible to [use fourier functions to add a second seasonality](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/).

I need to forecast gas consumption composed by a daily, weekly (week days-weekend), yearly seasonality. Does it make sense to apply three times the [STL decomposition by LOESS](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/stl.html)? The reason is that I applied the fourier method and I have bad results but I don't know if it is only because I applied it wrong.

I'm interested in the theoretical explanation, but here you find also the code:

ARIMA + 2 STL:

```
b <- ts(drop(coredata(dat.ts)), deltat=1/12/30/24, start=1)
fit <- stl(b, s.window="periodic")
b <- seasadj(fit)
dat.ts <- xts(b, index(dat.ts))

# The weekdays are extracted
dat.weekdays <- dat.ts[.indexwday(dat.ts) %in% 1:5]
dat.weekdaysTS <- ts(drop(coredata(dat.weekdays)), frequency=24, start=1)
fit <- stl(dat.weekdaysTS, s.window="periodic")
dat.weekdaysTS <- seasadj(fit)

arima <- Arima(dat.weekdaysTS, order=c(3,0,5))
```

With fourier:

```
dat.weekdays <- dat.ts[.indexwday(dat.ts) %in% 1:5]
dat.weekdaysTS <- ts(drop(coredata(dat.weekdays)), frequency=24, start=1)
z <- fourier(ts(dat.weekdaysTS, frequency=365.25), K=5)
arima <- Arima(dat.weekdaysTS, order=c(3,0,5),xreg=z)
```

Comment: If this does not get answered here, consider migrating it to the statistics site (stats.stackexchange.com) where you will be more likely to find experts in [time series](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series).